# Natural movement to polygon Hair

Tags: mesh, physics, hair

I'm trying to make a polygon type hair, which moves as naturally as in the first gif, but it doesn't see like it and it doesn't stay in its place, (I used the softbody for the hair anyway) is there a way to get a more natural movement?

[image: this is exactly what I want to reach]
[image: this is my model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with how you weight painted the mesh. If I remember correctly, if you weight painted it at "the roots", the part of the mesh that is not weight painted should move. Or it could be the other way around. So just to be sure, here are some videos to help you out on the softbodies issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2tM_LS8jIA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1lHca7I3So

Hopefully, these videos can lead you into the right direction.

Comment: oh thanks, looks like these explain me better how softboies works, (I'm still new with animation and such)